# Bmw 320 d 2011 n47t

Tags: engine

I've got my timing chain fixed before it was too late . I had a great experience with my local dealer and replaced it free of charge , my question is , will it ever get this bad again? I got a 2 year waranty on the job , but was wondering if it will be causing problems again .

Comment: "will it ever get this bad again?" - You have not described the problem in this question. Your question is too vague and incomplete. Please EDIT your question after referring to - http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask